# Why is my 4 year old feral rescue pooping on the living room area rug every night?

Tags: cats, toilet-training, feral

My feral cat that is is now 4 yrs old (I rescued him when he was around 1 year old!)started pooping on my living room area rug. He never did that before. He seems perfectly healthy with no signs of being ill. I have tried changing places where I put his liter box, tried different liters. I had another rescue who us about 6 months older than him and she has always hated him. Only recently in the past 6 months have learned to tolerant of each other!  Please help! Thank god he doesn't pee anywhere but in his box! The

Comment: Has your cat been to the vet? Is he declawed? Is he neutered? Have you bought a new box? Have you added multiple boxes in different locations? Has anything else in your house changed? What litter have you tried? Have you locked him in a small room with the box for 1-3 days? How have you cleaned the living room rug?

Comment: I'm going to mark your question as a duplicate right now, but please come back and [edit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/posts/17903/edit) the answers to these questions into your post so we can help you. There are just too many possibilities without this information.